# ADF Rich faces equivalent of jQuery add/remove Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-adf

I'm using ADF Rich Faces and in a client listener I would like to toggle the css class of an element. What is the correct Adf Faces way of doing that? I come from a jQuery / AngularJS background.  Can I get a handle on a raw dom element via the rich faces client api? I have read that dom manipulation should be avoided and to use the ADF rich client api for any dom changing. Anyways what object should I be using here? Here is my skeleton handler function.

```
 function _toggleQuickLinks(event){

        var source = event.source();

        event.cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove toggle the styleClass attribute of an ADF component at runtime you can do something like the following:

```
var styleClass = '';

function _toggleQuickLinks(event){
 var component = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("myComponentId"); 
 //If the component is the one that is triggering the event you can easily do
 //var component = event.getSource();
 if(styleClass==''){ //just For the first time
    styleClass = component.getStyleClass();
 }

 if(component.getStyleClass()==''){
    component.setStyleClass(styleClass);
 }else{
    component.setStyleClass('');
 }
 event.cancel();
}
```

ps: You need to make sure that the component has clientComponent attribute equals true